# Mountain Lion, export $PATH to .bash_profile, permission denied?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I can do this:

```
sudo nano .bash_profile
```

But when I do this:

```
sudo echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I get this error message:

```
-bash: /Users/mycomputer/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

When I do ls -al:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root         staff     27 10 Aug 12:22 .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick fix: do "sudo bash", to actually assume root privileges, THEN do the echo. It will work. sudo echo still uses your real uid, so it fails.

Comment: Note: his is a "quick fix". The downside is that I seem to always have to "sudo bash" to edit my profile now...just a note for people seeing this post.

Comment: that is because the profile file has been owned by root. You created it under sudo. Instead, next time you sudo do chown _your_user ~/.bash_profile (or instead chmod 666 it). That way you won't need to do the sudo.